# asp.net web application goes to login page after about 15 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application, and for some reason which I cannot figure out, It goes to the login page every 15 minutes (I believe the session is idle). I have no where web config file that specify a timeout even close to that. Has anyone ever had an issue like this or know where I could look to try and fix the problem? thanks for any help.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" 
         timeout="90" 
         defaultUrl="~/" 
         name="" 
         protection="All" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the session timeout:

```
<sessionState timeout="90" />
```

Also if you are using the ASP.NET Session and it is stored InProc, note that the web server might recycle the AppDomain under different circumstances such as a certain period of inactivity or some memory or CPU thresholds are reached. When the AppDomain is recycled everything that you might have stored in memory disappears. So make sure to check your Application Pool configuration in IIS to verify those values as well.

Comment: Will try <sessionState
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="90" />